# Eclipse Java Template adding extends or throws to class name

Tags: java, eclipse

So I've been trying to create a nice java template for when I'm creating a new java class. Currently all my new classes are looking the same, and so I've been working on building a template so that I don't have to type the same thing over and over 20+ times.

I've figured out how to include the imports and comments needed, but I can't figure out how to extend or throw things. For example, if I wanted to say:

```
public class test throws Exception{

}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

I thought it might be somewhere near

```
${typecomment}

${type_declaration}
```

However if I try to add it before the typecomment, it just goes before the class name (same for if I go between the two) and if I enter it after type_declaration it just goes to the end of the file after the last curly brace

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying?

This is pretty similar to what my template looks like right now:

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}
import java.util.*;
/**
*
*@author 
*@version 28 May 2015
**/
${type_declaration}
```

When I create a new class called test it creates a file that looks like:

```
package unfinished;
import java.util.*
/**
 * @author
 * @version 28 May 2015
**/
public class test {

}
```

Which is a great start, but I want it to stay

```
public class test extends bicycle{

}
```

Comment: Can you add the template you have so far to your question? Also, which context are you using for your template?

Comment: @MartinCarney Edited, hopefully that's got what you want. I'm making my edits in `preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates > Code > New Java files`

Comment: @MartinCarney I'm pretty new to Eclipse templates. I'm doing this through the Templates in the Preferences screen, and not the Templates view under `Window > Show View > Templates`

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Given the additional information you've provided:

For the "New Java files" code style template, you can't (or shouldn't even if you could) specify what it extends because you specify that in the `New Class` dialog.

It also doesn't make sense to add a `throws` declaration for a class. If you want to add a `throws` declaration to a default constructor, that would make sense. If you want to add in a default constructor from a template, you could edit the "Class body" code style template, but I'd recommend writing a content assist template instead, since the code style template is always applied to every single file, whereas content assist templates are only used when you specifically choose them.

To add a content assist template, go to Preferences : Java : Editor : Templates, and click "New...". Set the Context to "Java", then type out your constructor.

To use your new template, type its name in a Java file, and hit `ctrl-space` to activate content assist, then select your template from the list. (Content assist will automatically choose the top option if there's only one option when you hit `ctrl-space`.

---

(Old answer, running under the incorrect assumption we were talking about Content Assist templates rather than Code Style templates:)

If you're always extending/implementing/throwing the same thing, just hardcode it in your template.

But if you're wanting to tab through in autocomplete mode and specify which class to extend, etc., you can use any arbitrary name for it.

For example, I have to make a bunch of BD methods, so I put together this template:

```
public ${Type:return_type} ${name}(${}) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = Database.getConnection();
    ${BaseDAO:elemType} dao = new ${BaseDAO}(conn);
    try {
        return dao.${name}();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        Database.closeConnection(conn);
    }
}
```

`${name}` is just an arbitrary tag, it doesn't correspond to anything in "Insert Variable". Every time `${name}` appears in my template, whatever the user types in one will appear in all instances. I could just as easily put `${foo}` or `${anyArbitraryThingIWant}` and get the same result. I think this is the easiest way to answer your question.

---

The following bits aren't really in answer to your question, just explaining some of the items from my example.

`${Type:return_type}` lets me set the method's return type. Since I named it "Type", the default return type will be the `Type` class, which in my program is an object with a name, id, and description.

`${}` is an empty tab-able entry. Unfortunately I'm not able to use it to pass the method's parameters into the call to `dao.${name}(...)` because it copies over verbatim to every matching instance, and declaring method parameters doesn't match referencing them. I.e. if I enter "String str" into `${}`, it would put "String str" where I'm calling the corresponding dao method, which isn't correct syntax.

Comment: I'm fine hard coding it if I can figure out how. I haven't been able to figure out what `${typecomment}` and `${type_declaration}` do. I'm pretty sure once I figure that out the hard code would just be `public class ${type_name}` throws...